# Есть код для парсинга файла с подсчётом повторяющихся слов, но при сохранении результата сохраняется только последнее слово

Tags: python, парсер

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            a = (str(word) + ' ' + str(line.count(word)))
            print(a)
with open('text_out.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(a)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас каждый раз `a` перезаписывается. Вот исправление.

```
a = ''
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            a += (str(word) + ' ' + str(line.count(word))) + '\n'
            print(a)
with open('text_out.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(a)
f.close()
```

Comment: спасибо сработало :-)

Comment: можете еще с одним кодом помочь? Анологичная ситуация, но почему то это логика выдает мне ошибку